# Running a webserver behind a firewall I have no access to

Tags: firewall, webserver

I'm having a bad time in my student appartment: I want to run a webserver on my Laptop, which should be reachable from outside of the net.

I'm sitting behind some proxy-server that passes outgoing packets to the matching server but when it comes to incoming messages - it wouldn't route them correctly to my PC. (Seems like packets only get passed if some PC from within the student-flat is already connected to the sending server)

In the past I had a small virtual private server that was sending incoming website-requests over a reverse shell to my PC. Which then returned the website content, and the visitor could see my website. Sadly I don't have that server anymore...

Do you have any idea that might solve my problem?

Comment: Do you know if you are just behind a firewall, or is there a router involved?

Comment: phew.... good question maybe I'll find out later via IPtrace or packet sniffing, but I assume there is a router involved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, there's no easy way to do this and any way i can think of is an ugly hack. You have no public ip address (which makes it hard), some proxy server (which makes things harder) and no real access. I'm sure there's some matters of policy to address as well.

The ONE hack i can think of which might help would be to set up an ipv6 tunnel to your webserver, then using a public 6-4 proxy for users to connect. You'd as such be able to connect via the ipv6 tunnel, have a public (ipv6) address, and in theory your users should be able to connect then. It would, naturally, need some testing to get right, since i have no clue of the exact nature of your firewall and proxy.

I'd use [freenet6](http://www.gogo6.com/freenet6) with the gw6c client (though the windows client should work through) with the v6udpv4 method (which works behind a nat). My clients would likely want to use the [sixxs website gateway](http://www.sixxs.net/tools/gateway/) for access.

Comment: interesting... does it have to be a ipv6 tunnel? If yes, could you explain why?

in addition to that I'm a little confused: do I have to setup a Tunnel from my PC(running the webserver) to the proxy?

Comment: two reasons - firstly, its an 'easy' way to get a public ip address, and one of the tunneling methods works behind a firewall with no config. The proxy is to provide ipv4 clients access to the ipv6 server. You set up a tunnel from your pc to a tunnel broker who gives you a ipv6 address. You then use a 6 to 4 website gateway to access it (which works around most clients being ipv4)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have the same situation, I did this ipv6 tunnel by freenet6, works like magic. I would just like to note that you don't need 6-4proxy or sixxs website gateway for your lients with ipv4 connection to come in, all the have to do is access your server using your delegated domain http://youraccountname.broker.freenet6.net and they are good to go.

Comment: The answer is getting muddled in the details about your situation.  Could you rewrite starting with the answer, then the supporting details?

Comment: Sadly registration is closed for freenet6 so I can't get a delegated domain